# How to add additional argument to call function inside function with json arguments in postgres

Tags: json, postgresql, function, parameters

Basically I have `child_function(arguments json)`

And inside this function, I'm calling another function with exactly the same arguments as `child_function` using:

```
select * from main_function(arguments)
```

However I want to add some fixed parameter (e.g. 'childFunction': true) while calling `main_function()`, is it possible? And how?

Answer (score 0):

Concatenation did the job:

```
select * from main_function( (arguments::jsonb || '{"childFunction": true}'::jsonb)::json )
```